# gnome_rr_config_apply

Tags: 18.04

I tried using the gnome_rr_config_apply () api in Ubuntu 18.04 ,my libgnome-desktop version is 3.17 ,this API is seems to not doing anything and is not able to change the resolution and not returning any error .

Same API (gnome_rr_config_apply ())  I tried in Ubuntu 16.04 ,there libgnome-desktop version was 3.12 , this API was working fine and I am able to change the resolution .

It will be really helpful if  anyone can please let me know why gnome_rr_config_apply () api in Ubuntu 18.04 is not working .

Comment: The [GNOME documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-desktop/stable/gnome-desktop-gnome-rr-config.html#gnome-rr-config-apply) says that "gnome_rr_config_apply is deprecated and should not be used in newly-written code.". This may be a reason. But this function is still available even [on GNOME 3.34](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=gnome_rr_config_apply&literal=1). Do you have any errors stored in last variable (`GError **error`)?

Comment: The command returns :
code as 19 
message : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBUS.Error.UnknownMethod : MEthod ApplConfiguration not implemented on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig
I found below link which has list this as a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1714410